# Auto click a html button

Tags: html, css

Ho can i make this button `<div class="nav next"><button><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button></div>` auto click every 30 seconds ?

Comment: You should tag with JavaScript.

Comment: This isn't going to happen with css or html. You'll need to use javascript for that... Also, not sure where your going with this, but if it's a slideshow or something, you'll probably want it to advance differently than *auto clicking every 30 seconds*

Comment: That depends on what this button does. Does this button refresh the page, because if it does, there is a much better way.

Comment: no it's clicking there a slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you would trigger a click event on the button every 30 seconds using jQuery:

```
<div class="nav next">
    <button><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button>
</div>

<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            setInterval(function(){
                $('.nav.next > button').click();
            }, 30000)

        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about make the click code from Community but add for it to load on Iframe, then hide it

```
<div class="nav next">
<button onclick="loadMe();"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button> 
<iframe id="iframe" src="#" style="display:none"/>
</div>
<script>
function loadMe(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#iframe").attr("src", $(".nav.next > button a").attr("src"));
}
</script>
```

If you got what I mean as

you can use iframe as container